# What will be a best solution for running multiple Selenium instances with Chrome profiles on local PC with Windows when testing involves mouse actions

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, virtual, display

I'm looking for an advice how can I run multiple Selenium instances with Chrome profiles on local PC with Windows when testing involves mouse actions. I know that I need a some kind of virtual display to achieve that. Here is a little bit of context:
The purpose of my tests is to extract information from a variety of websites. Some of these sites require performing certain interactions, including mouse actions. To make this process more efficient, I divided the input URLs into two and ran the same code parallel on my second screen, with each half of the screen dedicated to a separate browser. This solution worked well, but now I need to process even more websites and I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to run multiple instances simultaneously.

From my own research, I know that the browser controlled by Selenium needs to be on top of the screen and elements need to be visible. Otherwise Selenium won't click/move mouse etc. I've found a solution where people used PyVirtualDisplay, but unfortunately, it doesn't work on Windows. Headless mode is also not an option because some websites won't process properly in that mode. I'm thinking that using a VM could be an option, but I don't know if that won't be an overkill here.

If anyone got some experience in that regard, I would be grateful for sharing some informations.

Best regards!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the browser being on "top".   The driver will take care of that.  The biggest hurdle is the resources that each browser will use up.  It sounds like you will want a remote grid with lots of machines/nodes.

Comment: Oh I don't really need that much browsers opened. I think that like 5 will make it, but from my testing I know that each browser needs to be on top. For e.g. When I've got 2 browsers set to full screen on my second display one which is on top is making progress all the time. The second one is getting stopped on the first mouse hover/click (I use that combo for some of the websites, because they seem to track mouse position). That's why I'm not sure how should I set it up.